# Service Area Polygons Differ When Running in Desktop Vs Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, network-analyst, service-area

I generated some service area polygons using Desktop 10.2.1 (long story why) a couple years back using nothing but the default parameters, and then tried recreating them in Pro yesterday using (as far as I can tell) the same parameters and the same network dataset, but the polygons generated using Pro look significantly different from the ones generated in Desktop, and I'm having trouble figuring out why. I looked at one of the polygons that hit a node (which was a 4-way intersection), and then stopped, but when I measured the finishing distance from the final node, each distance was different, even though the speed limits along all the roads was the same. Maybe there is some aspect of generating service areas that I am not understanding, so I was wondering if anyone could tell me why?

Comment: I'm having the same problem and I already sent to Esri Inc. I'll get back to you when I get a solution.

Comment: Thanks, Sidonia, please do.